# Summarize two tables into new one in R

Tags: r, merge, datatables

I have these two different tables :

```
#table1 all patients that have RNASeq data
experimental.strategy | submitter.id
      RNA-Seq         | TCGA-AA-3867
      RNA-Seq         | TCGA-F4-6809
      RNA-Seq         | TCGA-AA-3562
                    ...
```

#table2 all patients that have miRNAseq data

```
experimental.strategy   | submitter.id
      miRNA-Seq         | TCGA-A6-6650
      miRNA-Seq         | TCGA-AZ-4308
      miRNA-Seq         | TCGA-AA-A02Y
                     ...
```

There are patients with just one data available, so I have three kinds of patients: *with only RNA-Seq data, with only miRNA-Seq data, and patients with both miRNA-Seq and RNA-Seq data available.*

**I want to create a new table with all patients IDs summarizing the data of those tables like this:**

```
submitter.id |  miRNA-Seq  |  RNA-Seq  |  Paired
TCGA-4T-AA8H |      0      |     1     |    0
TCGA-5M-AAT5 |      1      |     1     |    1
TCGA-3L-AA1B |      1      |     0     |    0
TCGA-AA-A02Y |      0      |     1     |    0
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. Not all IDs are in table 3, it's just all patients with BOTH data present (rnaseq AND mirnaseq), roughly half of patients are in table 3 because there are patients with only RNAseq data and there are some more with only miRNAseq data. That's why if there's a patient with 'miRNA-Seq' as 1 and the same for 'RNA-Seq' it's necessarily paired too and 'paired' is 1

Comment: But why do you need `Table 3` when you can join `Table 1` and `Table 2` to get required information that is present in `Table 3`?

Comment: Thank you @JasonMathews I didn't see that, you are right I can get the info with just two tables

Comment: @JasonMathews would you like to post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you need the third table for when you can get all the required information from Table 1 and Table 2? Use `full_join` to `merge` `Table 1` and `Table 2` and get the required result shown below

```
## Input Data

df1 <- read.table(text = "experimental.strategy  submitter.id
      RNA-Seq          TCGA-AA-3867
      RNA-Seq          TCGA-F4-6809
      RNA-Seq          TCGA-AA-3562", header = TRUE)

df2 <- read.table(text = "experimental.strategy    submitter.id
      miRNA-Seq          TCGA-AA-3867
      miRNA-Seq          TCGA-F4-6809
      miRNA-Seq          TCGA-AA-A02Y", header = TRUE)
   

df1 <- df1 %>% rename(RNA_Seq = experimental.strategy) %>%
  mutate(RNA_Seq = str_replace(RNA_Seq, "RNA-Seq","1")) %>%
  mutate(RNA_Seq = as.numeric(RNA_Seq))


df2 <- df2 %>% rename(miRNA_Seq = experimental.strategy) %>%
  mutate(miRNA_Seq = str_replace(miRNA_Seq, "miRNA-Seq","1")) %>%
  mutate(miRNA_Seq = as.numeric(miRNA_Seq))


df1 %>% full_join(df2, by = ("submitter.id")) %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric,coalesce,0) %>% group_by(submitter.id) %>%
  mutate(Paired = if_else((RNA_Seq == 1 & miRNA_Seq == 1), 1, 0)) 

## Ouput

  RNA_Seq submitter.id miRNA_Seq Paired
    <dbl> <chr>            <dbl>  <dbl>
1       1 TCGA-AA-3867         1      1
2       1 TCGA-F4-6809         1      1
3       1 TCGA-AA-3562         0      0
4       0 TCGA-AA-A02Y         1      0
```

Comment: thank you so much, now that I know I've could use full_join I see that the table3 is unnecessary!